# Hide all rows that do not match label c#

Tags: c#

I want to hide all rows in datagridview that do not match the text in Access.text label, How would I accomplish this? This code hides all rows when the program is run

```
    private void Access_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingContext[productionBindingSource].SuspendBinding();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.productionDGV.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() != Access.Text)
            {
                row.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        BindingContext[productionBindingSource].ResumeBinding();
    }
```

Comment: The event is being called for each character  you enter but you never make any row visible again.. Change to `row.Visible = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() == Access.Text` - This will still make for a rather nervous user experience. Consider changing the logic..

Comment: Thank you for that, but what do I change? The row.Visible = false; ? or  if (row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() != Access.Text)?

Comment: the new code replaces both. please make sure you understand the syntax! you may want to put parenthesis around the comparison.

Comment: remove the if statement all together and put the line of code @TaW suggested.

Comment: I usually copy to new table which really is links to original table.  DateTable newTable = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("Column A") == 123).CopyToDataTable();